# I deleted default python on fedora and now getting errors

Tags: python, linux, pip, fedora

I recently deleted the default python version on Fedora 31 and installed python 3.9 then made it as default, now I have multiple versions of python.
If I type: `whereis python` in my terminal this list appear:

```sh
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.9-config /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3.9-x86_64-config /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib64/python3.9 /usr/lib64/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.9 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz /usr/src/Python-3.7.4/python
```

If I type `pip` then I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`

Also multiple packages are broken such as `dnf`, `argcomplete`, `pip`, etc. 
I cannot update or install anything.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Deleting the default python is a **bad idea** on any modern distro I'm aware off, because many system tools are directly tied to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions and didn't work, however I ended up backing up my data and completely deleting the OS, then I downloaded the last version of fedora and restored my data on it.
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Grab/Download the original python RPMs for your distro and reinstall them that way if they're not still cached under `/var` ....

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.9 you should use pip3...So install python3-pip.
That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this unfortunate situation as well on Fedora 35. `dnf`, `yum`, and a bunch of other things broke.

I didn't manage to get Python 3.10 back through `dnf`, `yum`, or `apt-get`. I downloaded the rpm from https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/python3-3.10.0-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html. It did require a dependency of python3-libs which I downloaded from: https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/python3-libs-3.10.0-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html.

I installed `python3-libs` first with `sudo rpm -i python3-libs-3.10.0-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm --force` as there were some file writing conflicts. I ran the same command for the `python3.10` rpm with the `--force` flag as well since there were 2 conflicts. After that, everything worked perfectly! Managed to dodge having to do a full reinstall.